# JETTY- HTML Publisher - Jenkins - Extent Reports - Images are broken 404 not found

Tags: selenium, jenkins, extentreports

The extent report that I generate running a Java Selenium project on a CentOS machine with jenkins it is showing partially correct.
The issue comes when trying to view the screenshots that I have attached into the extent report on Jenkins on png format
I am using HTML Publisher plugin on the latest version

I have already set this command on the jenkins command line
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")

[Extent Report on Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J3sK.jpg)

The strange thing is when navigating directly on the CentOS file explorer and going to that path inside the jenkins workspace and opening the html report it is showing correctly as expected
[Extent Report opened inside CentOS explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8OZg.jpg)

Has someone faced this issue before?

Edit:
This is the way I have the report inside a folder, including the jpg or png images at the same level of the html report [files at same level of html report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rINCM.png)

EDIT: I have found a new important information for the issue. I contacted a security teammate and he told me this was related to a configuration issue since port 8080 is listening correctly.

Since Jenkins standalone is using a Jetty Http server it might be an issue with this.

Entering the jenkins logs I got this new information filtering the Jetty logs:
[JETTY LOGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt74k.jpg)
Now I am working on troubleshooting this with the information with the logs

Comment: Setting `System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")` blank as you have disables ALL VSP protections and potentially leaves you exposed. But that should also display the content, so if still no content, then undo that. At least if done in the groovy console, it only lasts as long as the next restart.

Comment: The issue might be related to how I have the report created on the folder tree? This is the way I have it, I have the jpg or png images at the same level of the html report

Answer (score 0):

When requesting image not found, the file not allowed

Update your Jenkins Content Security Policy. With type into console the following commands:

```
System.clearProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP");
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-scripts; default-src *; img-src * data: ;");
```

Go to `Manage Jenkins -> Script Console` on your jenkins